# Lock a cell if the adjacent cell is empty - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

What I want to get is that if a cell in the range "D4: D14" is empty, the adjacent cell is locked. My code is the following but it doesn´t work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Intersect(Range("D4:D14"), Target)

    If rng Is Nothing Then

    Else
        If IsEmpty(Target) Then
            rng.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True
        Else
            rng.Offset(0, 1).Locked = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just saw your edit. I already incorporated both scenarios since I was unsure which one were you after :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to get is that if a cell in the range "D4: D14" **is empty**, the adjacent cell **is locked**.

In your code if the cell is empty you are setting the `.Locked` property to `False` whereas I guess you want the opposite?

This works for me

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Dim aCell As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Range("D4:D14"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect "MYPASSWORD" <~~ Change this to the actual password
        For Each aCell In Range("D4:D14")
            If Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) = 0 Then _
            aCell.Offset(, 1).Locked = True Else _
            aCell.Offset(, 1).Locked = False
        Next
        ActiveSheet.Protect "MYPASSWORD" <~~ Change this to the actual password
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Also ensure that the sheet is protected to see the effect of locked cells.

**EDIT**

The title of the question says

> Unlock a cell if the adjacent cell is empty - Excel VBA

In such a case

```
            If Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) = 0 Then _
            aCell.Offset(, 1).Locked = True Else _
            aCell.Offset(, 1).Locked = False
```

becomes

```
            If Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) = 0 Then _
            aCell.Offset(, 1).Locked = False Else _
            aCell.Offset(, 1).Locked = True
```

NOTE: If the above code still doesn't work then type this in the Immediate window and press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, The tittle was incorrect, I've edit it. I´ve also correct the logic of my code.

Comment: See my comment below your question :) Like I mentioned there, I have included both scenarios :)

Comment: I´ve run your code but it doesn´t seem to work. When I type in any cell of the range "D4:D14", a message appears and says, "The property locked of the clase range can`t be assigned".

Comment: I've used edit application.enableevents=true in the inmediate window and now it works as desired. But anymway when I type anything in the range "D4:D14", the same message appears. Is there anyway to remove that message?.

Comment: Yes, my worksheet is protected and the range "D4:D14" is unlocked.

Comment: But you want to lock/unlock Range "E4:E15" via code... remember we are using `OFFSET` ;) So you will have to unprotect the sheet in the code and then protect it in the end

Comment: I don´t get what you mean in "remember we are using OFFSET ;) So you will have to unprotect the sheet in the code and then protect it in the end" . Can you explain that in code or be more clear to me. Huge thanks!

Comment: Sure. What is our objective? To lock the cells in "E4:E15" if a cell in "D4:D15" is empty. Correct?

Comment: Yes, I stated that in the beggining of the discussion.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42057/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-creamstat)